# cp leading zero

Tags: linux, bash

My script:

```
for i in {99..100}
 do
  cp dummy.shp  dummy.{ printf %04d%s ${i}\_shp}
 done
```

I want to have:

```
dummy.0099_shp
dummy.0100_shp
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for i in {99..100}
do
  cp dummy.shp dummy.`printf "%04d%s_shp" ${i}`
done
```

Answer (score 4):

```
for i in {0099..0100}
do
  cp dummy.shp  dummy.${i}_shp
done
```

Comment: Requires Bash 4 in order to have leading zeros in the result.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you:

```
parallel cp dummy.shp {} ::: $(seq -f'dummy.%04g_shp' 99 100)
```

but wouldn't:

```
for i in 0099 0100
do
  cp dummy.shp dummy.${i}_shp
done
```

or:

```
cp dummy.shp dummpy.0099_shp; cp dummy.shp dummy.0100_shp
```

be easier?